When you load a save, does the Surface also experience the load?
In Undertale, when you load a save, does the Surface also experience the load?
Flowey used to mess with the timelines all the time—did he let time flow longer than ever before, or is the clock always ticking on the Surface, allowing the human to fall into the Underground?

This is VTC'ed as 'Needs details' (and not having played the game I'm also not entirely sure what you're talking about), so can you expand a little on the scenario here? I'm assuming the game plays diegetically with the concept of saving/loading? (Still I VTLO, because the question has a logical underpinning.)

@Joachim to anyone familiar with the game, it needs no further details.

Within the mechanics of the game, "The Surface" is a couple of scenes that are shown during one of the endings. It is not possible for the Surface to "experience" anything. It is not possible to verify the status of the Surface at any point in the game other than during the ending because it is not a reachable playable area. Any answer to this question would necessarily dive deep into the realm of headcanon.

@HitenStyle this is a valid question. The OP is asking if according to the game lore the ability to "load" a previous point in time affect the world outside the barrier too or it is just the monsters that go thru the rewind. If you have reason to think that the game doesn't give enough info to answer, neither mechanically nor in its world lore... then that is a perfectly fine answer to post.

As far as I'm aware, or at least how I've always viewed saving, loading, resetting, etc. It would impact the entire timeline, surface included. Although this has 0 actual impact on gameplay and as stated above cannot be confirmed in-game.
